# How te send push notifications from FCM using Postman

Tags: firebase, postman

I'm using the documentation from firebase to try send a message to an device using the Post method. [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message) and 
here is my example:[authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDapq.png) where has the My_key i put the server key from firebase cloud and here is the body [body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdurA.png) And I'm reciving an 401 status error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue you are facing is because of your Authorization value in the header.

Based on your screenshot, you seem to be trying to use a key for authentication. Hence I assume you are using legacy protocol.

In this case for your authorization header value, try giving `key=My_key` instead of `bearer My_key`

Hopefully, this should solve your issue.

Refer firebase documentation to authorize send requests - https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server